# Why does not my printer work?

Tags: drivers, printer

Please forgive me if this question has already been asked. The fact is that I do not speak English well.
What is the problem? The system correctly identified my printer and found drivers for it, installed (Canon LBP2900). In the settings of the system / printers, it is displayed. But if I send a file from the same WPS or from the image viewer, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may not be sent to the right printer....or the printer needs to be power cycled. In the printer settings, you should note if the printer appears with a green indicator over the printer icon. If not, it's not ready t print.

Usually when I print, I go to print, a dialog box asking me to choose my printer pops up (very important step), I select the correct printer and then hit the Print button within the dialog box.